# state not updating in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have created a login form where user need to input his email id and OTP. below is my code  -

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from '../api/axios';

const useLogin = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

    const auth = async (value, OTP) => {

        let config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/user/generateToken',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'value'
            },
            data: {
                username: value,
                password: OTP
            }
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios(config);
            if (response.data.Status === "Failure") {
                throw response.data.Message;
            } else {
                setUser(true);
                return { status: response.data.Status, isAuth: user }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setUser(false);
            return { status: undefined, message: err, isAuth: user };
        }

    }

    return { auth, user };


}

export default useLogin
```

Everything is working fine here only problem is when i'm calling this function in my component i'll receive isAuth always false. Below is my component code -

```js
import React, { Fragment, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import ScaleLoader from "react-spinners/ScaleLoader";
import '../css/login.css';
import '../css/common.css';
import logo from '../assets/engageLogo.png';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import useLogin from './../hooks/useOTP';

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: #fff;
`;

const OTP = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [color] = useState("#ffffff");
    const [APIResponse, setAPIResponse] = useState(false);
    const [APIMessage, setAPIMessage] = useState('')
    const login = useLogin();

    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();

    const inputRef = useRef();
    const readRef = useRef();
    const buttonRef = useRef();

    const schema = Yup.object({
        otp: Yup.string().required("OTP is Required")
    });

    const handleChangeError = () => {
        return setAPIResponse(false)
    }

    const {
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        touched,
        errors,
    } = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            otp: "",
        },
        validationSchema: schema,
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
            buttonRef.current.disabled = true;
            setLoading(true);
            const loginCall = login.auth(location.state.email, values.otp);

            loginCall.then(response => {
                if (response.status === undefined || response.status === null) {
                    setLoading(false);
                    buttonRef.current.disabled = false;
                    setAPIResponse(true)
                    setAPIMessage(response.message)
                } else {
                    setLoading(false);
                    history.push({
                        pathname: '/dashboard',
                        state: { email: values.email }
                    });
                }
            })



        },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.focus();
        readRef.current.value = location.state.email;
    }, [location])

    return <Fragment>
        <div className="centered-form">
            <div className="centered-form__box">
                <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                    <img src={logo} className="img-fluid" width="150" alt="Logo" />
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="readEmail" className="form-label">Email</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="readEmail"
                            id="readEmail"
                            ref={readRef}
                            className="form-control" readOnly />

                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="otp" className="form-label">OTP</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="otp"
                            id="otp"
                            ref={inputRef}
                            onChange={(e) => { handleChange(e); handleChangeError(e) }}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            className="form-control" placeholder="Enter OTP" required />
                        {touched.otp && errors.otp
                            ? <div className="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid OTP</div>
                            : null}
                        {APIResponse
                            ? <div className="invalid-feedback">{APIMessage}</div>
                            : null}
                    </div>

                    <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button ref={buttonRef} className="btn btn-main">{loading ?
                            <ScaleLoader color={color} loading={loading} css={override} height={15} /> : <span>Login</span>}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
}

export default OTP
```

in `response` of `loginCall` i'll always get `isAuth: false`.
I want to use isAuth for protecting my routes. Just to check whether user has logged in or not.
why `setUser` is not updating the value here.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you include the response in JSON format?

Comment: the response is `{ status: 'Success', isAuth: false }`

Comment: Try `response.data.status === "Failure"` in the first if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because by the time you returning your `isAuth` value the `new user value` is not set yet. you need to know that `React setState` is asynchronous function.
just use the the boolean itself directly like this:

```
setUser(true);
return { status: response.data.Status, isAuth: true }
```

or in case of a rejection:

```
setUser(false);
return { status: undefined, message: err, isAuth: false };
```

Comment: in that case, there is no state changes, then how it will work for protected routes.Might be a dumb question ?

Comment: @AtalShrivastava the `user` state will be `changed` but not at that moment.

Comment: ok, so i can call this function in App.js and in my procted routes i can define user value will it work ?

Comment: why do you return the `isAuth` variable when it is just the same as `user` state, just use `user` state @AtalShrivastava

Comment: ok, i'll try now, then there is no need of isAuth

Comment: @AtalShrivastava good, if the answer was helpful try to accept the answer and give an upVote to it

Comment: sure, i'll do that.

Comment: At what moment this will update the state. i tried this remove the isAuth => call in App.js but it still came false.